# Shorthand along with arithmetic (SASS)

Tags: sass, arithmetic-expressions

I can't use shorthand when I need to use variable arithmetic in SASS,

This is expected result:

```
text-shadow: 0 -2px white;
```

But when I code this:

```
$shadow: 2px;
text-shadow: 0 -$shadow white;
```

But I get this:

```
text-shadow: -2px white;
```

How to fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution:

```
text-shadow: 0 #{-$shadow} white;
```